# Javascript/Jquery: How do i alert labels text that contains my search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains, textmatching

Hi I've searched and found different things based loosely around this and some more closely tied but I haven't been able to devise and create a workable solution for the problem I'm having:

***Summary:***

I am looking to create a view in a specific way due to my requirements. This is currently looking at using a self implemented Treeview style - I don't wish to use any kind of other plugins or pre-made views at the moment, because as you can see by the attached JS fiddle demo at the bottom, I can achieve this myself.

***Problem At Hand:***

This may be stupidly easy or straightforward and if so please forgive my incompetence but the problem is coming down to the  tags - which have text in-between like so:

```
<ul><checkbox class="collapsible" /><label>Value 1</label>...<ul>
```

now I have no problem retrieving this values - as there is quite a few in the list of them (one for each option). But finally the base of the problem is matching these to my search input. While I have used the very obvious and generic for each loop it has a problem actually matching the 'input' - my variable for the search input - and the label's text together - hence it wont alert the correct values and can sometimes alert all 15 values when only 4 may match...

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this - feel free to use any of the tree view code which works very nicely alongside the select boxes.

***Side note***

In my actual view these check boxes will be associated with the label names using an object class to populate the value. Also I want, not really alert the matching labels, but to highlight them -  so if anyone could help with that or suggest anything as well that would be nice - not the critical problem though. (sorry i know this is no help or use to you but I thought id enlighten you as to my reasons for alerting these labels.)

[MY JS FIDDLE DEMO - TREEVIEW](https://jsfiddle.net/mLbhLh89/16/) -- EDIT: this was the answer I needed (i will leave it here incase anyone else wants to use this), answer perfectly supplied by Radu Andrei

---

EDIT: I am not looking to alert based on any criteria asides the fact that the labels text matches the search text.

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mLbhLh89/4/ ? (your labels have spaces, i didn't trim the spaces or made the search case insensitive - fairly easy to do).

Comment: Just to clarify, you only want to grab the selected checkboxes label names?

Comment: sorry to clarify - i only want to alert the label values that match the text - selected or not is not a condition i am bothered by here. sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: @RaduAndrei - thank you for that! - its very helpful but perhaps you got slightly lost in the question. ill clear up a little more: I need it to highlght all matching the search for example i input "Num" into the search - id want all labels containing that string to become highlighted - Upvoted for a good quick and helpful answer to the highlighting though - thanks

Comment: @harrison this then https://jsfiddle.net/mLbhLh89/11/ ? Again, i didn't trim spaces nor did i make the search case insensitive, because i don't know if you need it or not.

Comment: @RaduAndrei - this is perfect!! exactly what i asked for - if you leave an answer i will quite happily accept it - i will probably change the casing matches for it at somepoint as well thanks - i added a couple of lines to remove the selected upon a new search - thanks for this!                                 Just one more quick one whether you can help or not - any idea if i can make it open all the way into the highlighted text so if say the tree is collapsed and i typed in 'Number 1' can i make it open to just far enough to show and highlight that value? so uncollapse all the necessary..?

Comment: The way you made the toggle, it's tricky to do, but as a general thought, to go up the chain with an action at each point use `.parentsUntil('selector')` -> `$(this).parentsUntil($('#topParent')).click();` This will not work because your collapse function will cascade to the children and negate the clicks, so you'll need to rethink that. Note that `parentsUntil` stops short of the selector, so wrap your big ul in another selector that's going to act as a stop point when goin up the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question can be found in the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/mLbhLh89/11/ `.`

Answer (score 0):

Try as shown in the fiddle

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mLbhLh89/14/)

I just updated your search function with following

```
$("#search").on("click", function() {
    $("label").each(function(i,v){

        if($(this).text().indexOf($("#search-criteria").val())>0){
        alert($(this).text());
        }
    });

});
```

It will find the search string in each label text and show an alert if found.

Comment: What about checking the parent if all children are manually checked? +1 tho

Comment: This is an awful solution - this will only check to see if its in the Select all or absolute child nodes - no other labels are ever alerted regardless of the input, sorry. by this i mean you will never get an alert for any 'Number #' which is not overtly useful for me. Thanks for attempting though.

Comment: Every label will be searched because of $("label"), I think so.